# CMake MSVC variable gets populated only after call to project

Tags: if-statement, cmake

I want to create my project name per my compiler (different names for MSVC or GNU).

I have the following code:

```
if(MSVC)
    project(Block3Windows ...)
else()
    project(Block3Linux ..)
endif()
```

These are the first commands in my *CMakeLists.txt* file. However, it always enters the `else` block.

It seems like the MSVC variable gets populated only after the call to project, to test it I've wrote the following:

```
if(MSVC)
    message(MSVC)
endif()
message(MSVC)
project(Block3Windows ...)
message("After Project")
message(MSVC)
```

I get the following printed:

First run:

```
After Project
MSVC
```

Second and later runs (with cache):

```
MSVC
After Project
MSVC
```

Why the `MSVC` from withing the first condition is never being printed ?

This behavior is not mentioned in the [MSVC documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/variable/MSVC.html)

Am I missing something? How do I create a project name per logic on my compiler environment?

I'm using CMake 3.17.2

Comment: `Why the MSVC from withing the first condition is never being printed ?` because it is populated after call to `project`.

Comment: So do you have another variable to use in order to logic project name based on it ? Or you must send it as program argument ?

Comment: `So do you have another variable to use in order to logic project name based on it ?` Well, you can (re-)write `project()` call and detect os manually I guess.. `Or you must send it as program argument ?` That would be strange, it would defeat the purpose of cmake.

Comment: Exactly, I want to avoid sending different parameters per the build machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about just a generic initial call to project, and then choose the name with the second call to project.

```
project(Block3)
if(MSVC)
    project(Block3Windows)
else()
    project(Block3Linux)
endif()
```

But I think that you *can* determine system by:

```
include(CMakeDetermineSystem)
if (MSVC)
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks, first approach (with the generic call to `project`) nailed it. Second approach still doesnt populate the variable before `project`.

Comment: :/ Ach, because `MSVC` is a macro for compiler? So then maybe `CMakeDetermineCompiler`. But then it can break in some corner case like `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` is set, so I think it's safer to just call a `project()`.

Comment: None of the `Determine` statements work. Indeed it would be prettier then using the generic call, but anyway - most importantly this issue has a *non command parameters* solution.